# How to capture a value in QTP from a webpage and email it to someone from outlook

Tags: qtp

I am trying to capture a value from a reports page:

It is a report I am generating, and there is a number on the webpage for errors, how do I capture that Value in QTP and copy it in a Excel file and send the file as email.

Attached is the reference pic for the report web page

[image: Web Report]

Comment: What are you using? just QTP? Do you want to do all of this automatically?

Comment: Yes, I am using QTP 11 on win 7, 
Actually I am looking for both ways, do it automatically or / and manually since I am trying this to dump in a Excel file and send it as attachment via email

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you use selenium/qtp for he web part, but to manage windows you will need Sikuli (Image based, easy) or AutoIt (More robust, harder). I hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You can create an output value for the text value of the errors `WebElement`. In order to identify the errors element you can use a regular expression that matches text (something like `\d+(\s\(\d+\))?`).

You should also use Visual Relations Identification to get the first field underneath the **Total Errors** header.

From that point you have the value and it's a straightforward matter of sending the email and or entering into excel.

Comment: Tried to come-up with the script, however I am still getting an issue while catching the value and passing it into the file.

I tried using selenium, however Selenium and IE do not work hand in hand hence QTP since this software majorly is used on IE in my company

Comment: @Umesh if you post some of the HTML source I may be able to help you create a QTP script

Answer (score 0):

if it's webtable read value using WebTable(“TableName”).GetCellData(i, ColumnName) using QTP. What is the class of that table ?

Code to write value to excel

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\pathtoexcel.xlsx")
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
strCellValue = objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Value
objWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = Valuefromwebtable
objWorkbook.Save
objExcel.Quit
```

Code to send Email

```
Set Objoutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set newEmailMail = Objoutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newEmailMail.Subject = "Message Subject to send"
newEmailMail.Body = "Message Body "
newEmailMail.RecipIents.Add(Email Address) 'Email Address
newEmailMail.Attachments.Add(File Attachment) ' Excel file created 
newEmailMail.Send
Set Objoutlook = Nothing
```